# merge overlapping sub-intervals

Tags: c++, merge

I actually tried this question in some different way

```cpp
#include"bits/stdc++.h"
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int> > overlap(vector<vector<int> > arr,int n){
    
    deque<int> q;
    q.push_back(arr[0][0]);
    q.push_back(arr[0][1]);
    int i=1;
    
    while(i<n){
        int j=0;

        if(q.back()>arr[i+1][j]){
            if(q.back()<arr[i+1][j+1]){
                q.pop_back();
                q.push_back(arr[i+1][j+1]);
            }
        }
        else{
            q.push_back(arr[i+1][j]);
            q.push_back(arr[i+1][j+1]);
        }
        
        i++;
    }
    
    vector<vector<int> > out(n,vector<int>(n,0));
    int k=0;
    
    while(!q.empty()){
        int l=0;
        out[k][l]=q.front();
        q.pop_front();
        out[k][l+1]=q.front();
        q.pop_front();
        k++;
    }
    
    return out;
}
```

but while running it isn't showing any output. Is there something wrong in my code or my approach is wrong

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger? I do not see any `main` or `print` so no output sounds ok?

Comment: I used  main function there. I want to get checked my merge function